# Get Headers & Footers into Corners

Tags: header-footer

How do I get the headers and footers to reach the top right and bottom right corners of the page? The placement just looks weird now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy} 
 \lhead{\huge top left header}
 \chead{}
 \rhead{\huge top right header}
 \lfoot{\huge left footer}
 \cfoot{\huge center footer}
 \rfoot{\huge right footer}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\huge Will the header and footer appear properly? Will they actually reach the corners of the page? Or will the text be much wider than the header and footer?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the order in which you load your packages.

Here, you are setting fancy specifications, before you have 
set the page dimensions using `geometry`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.8cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\lhead{\huge top left header}
\chead{}
\rhead{\huge top right header}
\lfoot{\huge left footer}
\cfoot{\huge center footer}
\rfoot{\huge right footer}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\huge Will the header and footer appear properly? Will they actually
reach the corners of the page? Or will the text be much wider than the
header and footer?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Can I ask how I might have figured this out on my own? This seems like something that would be very hard to discover independently...

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything That is more of a hunch based on experience. And I have faced similar situations where order of packages was important. In your particular case, you could ask why the headers and footers do not conform to page size. Then something must be wrong with the page size, leading you to `geometry`.

Comment: Though everything you wrote makes sense, I still don't think I would have inferred that package *order* was the problem.